# Сохранение отрисованного в Canvas'е в файл

Tags: canvas, java, android, файлы

Здравствуйте. Программирую под систему Android OS. Пишу виджет-класс, наследующий View. В методе обратного вызова (callback-method) - onDraw(Canvas canvas) происходит отрисовка графических примитивов и Bitmap'ов по мере взаимодействия пользователя с данным виджетом. Хотел бы реализовать метод, позволяющий сохранить все, что отрисовывалось в ходе многократного вызова onDraw на canvas'е, в файл (.jpg, .png). 
Каким образом вообще осуществляется сохранение всего отрисованного в каком-то объекте (в данном случае Canvas) в файл? Какая цепочка классов вообще нужна для такой операции? С текстовыми и двоичными файлами были потоки StreamWriter, FileWriter и т.д. Подозреваю и тут такое потребуется, но как вообще перейти от Canvas'а с его содержимым к конечному файлу картинки?
И можно ли сохранять файлы изображений в какие-то общедоступные всем каталоги? Скажем, есть ли в системе Android что-то наподобие "Мои Документы" или "Галерея"?
Заранее спасибо, и извините за слишком примитивные вопросы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По поводу вашего вопроса - ответ: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174875/android-canvas-to-jpg)
И дарю метод сохранения картинки в галерею:

```
private String saveImageToMediaStore(Bitmap source, String title, String desc){
    return MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), source,title, desc);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Выходит, что ваш метод, либо указания по ссылке на StackOverflow, сохраняют Bitmap (то есть графический объект изначально полученный из какого-то изображения) в файл.
А как сохранить все отрисованное на Canvas'е? Я имею в виду, все то, что было отрисовано методами drawRect, drawPath, drawArc и т.д. Ну или, хотя бы как все, что я рисую подобными методами преобразовать в Bitmap?

Comment: По идеи, Вы ведь этими методами рисуете на канве(на текущем объекте Canvas), вот и имеется ввиду, что нужно сохранить текущий объект Canvas в файл. Прочтите ответ на тот вопрос по ссылке и попробуйте подстроить его под свой вариант.
А далее, мой метод просто сохранит ваш битмэп в галерею.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Дальше попробую сам. Единственный вопрос: 
последний параметр desc в вашем методе. За что он отвечает. Интуиция меня покинула.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Пробуйте. В Андроиде только так и нужно.
desc - необязательный параметр. Служит описанием вставляемой картинки в галерею. Я передавал пустую строку и работало отлично.